# How to make dnscrypt-proxy auto start in Fedora 25

Tags: fedora, autostart, dnscrypt

When I install `dnscrypt-proxy`, I found no `dnscrypt-proxy.service` here.

I write a bash to launch it, and write a desktop file here, `~/.config/autostart/dnscrypt.desktop`

```
#!/bin/bash

zenity --password --title="sudo"|tr -d '\n'|sudo -S dnscrypt-proxy -R cisco -a 127.0.0.2:53 -u `whoami`
```

But it no work after input password. I can not found `gksudo` and `gnome-keyring-query` in the repo, so I use `zenity`.

Answer (score 0):

The distribution tarballs include a sample `dnscrypt-proxy.service`.

Alternatively you can just use the one suggested in the [official binary packages](https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy-installer) -- adjust the paths as required

```
[Unit]
Description=DNSCrypt client proxy
After=network.target
Before=nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/dnscrypt-proxy /etc/dnscrypt-proxy.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/O8LXbI9gkSvr0aD04AT0E15M1UNdIGYhyRLivL9gydE=   Considering that the dnscrypt-proxy is missing some files and not a complete package, I would like to install dnscrypt-proxy-gui. but this package is depend on so many packages, I hesitate.

Comment: Ouch, this package is very incomplete indeed. A lot of features are not available and the server won't even start with the default configuration file.